# how to integrate faster rcnn model in a desktop ui

Tags: performance, faster-rcnn

I am trying to integrate Faster R-ccn model in a desktop UI.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. I just finished doing the model, and I want to integrate it in a desktop UI. This is my first project, and I would like to ask assistance.